# Autohotkey - input for hotkey combinations - suspend for one keypress - fallthrough key

Tags: autohotkey

How do I:

1. Read (wait for and record) a single press (i.e. Shift-Alt-F5 )
2. Pass this recorded key combo to the program (i.e. Photoshop), without it running as a hotkey.

I tried this but it didn't work for my non ASCII hotkeys. It works for the t hotkey.

```
F6::
Suspend, On
Input, OutputVar, L1 M
Send, %OutputVar% 
Suspend, Off
return


F5::Run explorer
t::Run notepad
!+5::Run cmd
```

- F5 is a hot key that runs the program Explorer.
- F6 is a hot key that suspends all hotkeys for one press. And passes through the key combo as a non hot key
- When I am in firefox if I press F6 F5 it will fall through to firefox's refresh page action.
- When I press F5, without a preceding F6, it will open Explorer

Comment: Instead of capturing the keys (of undetermined length due to the various possible modifiers) with the input command, maybe you can trigger on something like WM_KEYUP. For every key that is pressed DOWN, track each pressed key (the modifier keys). Constantly monitor the last pressed key to see if it is released. This lifting up of the last pressed key would be your trigger that the hotkey was pressed and a trigger to to continue the script.

Comment: B.t.w. Can you show what have you done in the mean time to try to solve this issue?

Comment: I have been searching help, the web, and looking at key logger scripts... I can not see a clean solution... I am going to stick with having a hotkey that toggles the suspension of all hotkeys (except the toggle hotkeys hotkey), then toggle back on when I have passed the over shadowed keys to the underlying program.... I was hoping to save myself the extra button press of turning back on the hotkeys. I had this functionality in the linux window manager called sawfish using the function quote-event... Thanks for all your help Robert

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions.

1. Add the hotkeys you want to capture to your input like this:

   ```
   Input, OutputVar, L1, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
   ```

Otherwise these non-ascii keys are ignored by input.

Alternatively, make the behaviour of F5 key application specific.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinNotActive, Firefox
    F5::Run explorer
#IfWinNotActive
```

This way, your <kbd>F5</kbd> key will always launch IE, except when you work inside Firefox, then <kbd>F5</kbd> will be <kbd>F5</kbd> and reload your page.

Comment: Thanks... this answers the question, but I phrased it wrong... I want to be able to record a single hot key (maybe) COMBO press ( i.e. #r )... I think your solution only records one single key press (just the # in #r)... My example was made up.... I want to be able to press a hot key, then for it to suspend the script for just one hot key combo press ( i.e. #r ), pass those keys through and then toggle the suspended script.

Comment: Your real objectives are still not clear to me. Please try to be a specific as possible, not making up things. From what I read, I think you want the following: Press a hotkey (#r) to start a script. What should be done with any keystrokes while the script is running? Then when you hit (#r) again, stop the script? You talk about passing through "the" keys. What do you mean by that?

Comment: One can map Suspend to a key to easily toggle hotkey bindings on and off.... I want to toggle keybindings off on one key, then press a hotkey binding which is overshadowing a programs default behaviour, have it initiate the programs default behaviour and then straight away turn back on my hotkey bindings without having to press another key. Also, I would like to log to a file the keybindings pressed.

Comment: Let me try to write back what I read. In Ahk you have defined several hotkeys but you do NOT want these hotkeys to be activated under normal conditions. If you press one special activation hotkey, you then want the other hotkeys to be activated, but as soon as you have pressed (and executed) one hotkey, Ahk's behaviour should go back to the initial stage where the hotkeys (except the one used to activate the other hotkeys) are turned off again, so you can use these keys for their "native" function.

Comment: The bahaviour you are looking for can best be described (simulated) by using the Ahk pause function where you start with Ahk in pause mode (i.e. hotkeys do not work), then un-pause or activate Ahk (hotkeys are active) for one hotkey and after this one hotkey is pressed, have Ahk go back to pause mode again. Can you confirm this behaviour (I am not saying that this is the solution, I am first trying to get clear what kind of behaviour you are looking for).

Comment: I am looking for different behaviour... The example code I gave sort of does what I want... By pressing F6 it disables all hotkeys. Then waits for a single key to be pressed. It saves this key for later processing. It sends the key pressed to underlying program. Then turns back on hotkeys straight away.... However, it only works for single key presses. i.e. if I mapped the key t to open Explorer, if I pressed F6 t, it would not invoke Explorer but do the programs default behaviour i.e. in notepad it would enter a letter t... I want to be able for it to catch keybindings like !+5

Answer (score 1):

Based on your notes, I think that you want to do the following.
Use #r to block any input and start your script, then when you press #r again, the script stops and input is restored. When that is the case, you could try this:

```
#Singleinstance force
$#r::
If (MyToggle := !MyToggle) ; Toggle the value MyToggle True/False
    {
        ToolTip,Input  blocked [Win]+r,A_ScreenWidth/2-50,0
        BlockInput, on ; In Vista and above, you need to run AHK as admin or run AHK in compatility mode with Windows XP SP 3
        SetTimer RunMyScript, 500 ; Start the actual script in 500 ms outside of this script, so you can toggle
        Return
    }
Else
    {
        Tooltip
        BlockInput, off
        ;Reload ; This will KILL the "RunMyScript" IMMEDIATELY at an unpredictable location.
        Return
    }
return

RunMyScript: ; This script runs independently from the script above. The script stops after 10 loops and resets the input. [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del] still kills any script.
SetTimer RunMyScript, Off ; Turn the 500 ms timer off
loop, 10
{
    if (!MyToggle) ; Check the MyToggle variable to see if you need to stop the script. This will Exit the script at a predictable location.
        Exit

    SoundBeep, 600,600
    Sleep, 1000
}
BlockInput, off ; Allow keyboard & mouse input again. Warning the [Win] key key may be left activated, causing keyboard actions to start applications
Tooltip
Return
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Writing something to a log file can be done this way. Here I create a new logfile every day and for every entry you have to rpeat the last two lines (to get the actual time).

```
FormatTime, DateRef, %TimeNow%, yyyyMMdd ; Store current date in variable DateRef
MyLogFile = %A_ScriptDir%\LogFiles\LogFile-%DateRef%.txt ; Define the name of the log file.
FormatTime, TimeAbsolute, %TimeNow%, HH:mm:ss ; Use the current time to set the timestamp variable called TimeAbsolute used inside the Log File
FileAppend, `n`r| %TimeAbsolute% | Your hotkey and possibly in which application`n`r,%MyLogFile% ; Write logfile
```

Comment: Thanks for all your effort... my problem with logging to a file was that the key being recorded was not always in human readable form. Sometimes it was a symbol and not something like 'CTRL F5'

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet checked this, but I think this is what you are looking for...

```
FormatTime, DateRef, %TimeNow%, yyyyMMdd ; Store current date in variable DateRef
MyLogFile = %A_ScriptDir%\LogFiles\LogFile-%DateRef%.txt ; Define the name of the log file.
FileAppend, `n`r| %TimeAbsolute% | Your hotkey and possibly in which application`n`r,%MyLogFile% ; Write logfile
Suspend, on ; Start with hotkeys disabled
Return

Pause:: ; Use pause key to 'activate' the hotkeys
Suspend, Off ; Activate the hotkeys
SetTimer, Stop, 10000 ; If no hotkey is pressed within 10 seconds, deactivate the hotkeys aagain
Return

Stop: ; Deactivate the hotkeys
Suspend, on ; Deactivate the hotkeys
SetTimer, Stop, Off ; turn the stop timer off
Return

q:: ; use a key (q) as a hotkey
Soundbeep, 600,600 ; sound a short beep to show that it works
HotKeyType = "q key"
WinGet, ApplicationType, ProcessName, A
GoSub, Write
Return

Write:
SetTimer, Stop, Off ; Make sure that the stop timer is turned off
FormatTime, TimeAbsolute, %TimeNow%, HH:mm:ss ; Use the current time to set  the timestamp variable called TimeAbsolute used inside the Log File
FileAppend, `n`r| %TimeAbsolute% | %HotKeyType% used in %ApplicationType%`n`r,%MyLogFile% ; Write logfile
Suspend, On ; Disable the hotkeys again
Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to logging the keys, I specifically defined the keytype to be printed in the log-file as a text string, this way you can define your own text for each non-printable key.

I re-wrote the script in the following way:
When you press F6 once, and then another key (in this case F5), it will perform a beep (acts as a hotkey). If you press F6 twice, if will send F6 as if no hotkey was set. If you press F5 without first pressing F6, it will just send F5 as if no hotkey was active. Hope that this is what you wanted....

```
$F6::
If (MySuspend := !MySuspend) ; Toggle the value MySuspend True/False
{
        ToolTip Hotkeys On (F6),A_ScreenWidth/2-50,0
}
Else
{
    Tooltip
    Send, {F6}
}
return

$F5::
If MySuspend
{
    SoundBeep, 600, 600
    MySuspend := 0
    ToolTip
}
else
{
    Send, {F5}
}
Return
```

Comment: I noticed you sent a string representation of the key pressed to the log file. But you were not listening for ANY key to be pressed but mapped it to a hotkey and knew which keys had been pressed to invoke that particular instance. This solution scales really badly and is a pain to maintain and write.

Comment: The solution above is a hack that could be tweaked to solve the problem. However, it does not allow me to read and act on key presses not mapped to an auto hotkey (which was only really need for debugging). Also it is bad coding practice....  I want to be able to wait for ANY key to be pressed (i.e. Ctrl+y) and then act on it. The key being pressed may or may not be linked to a auto hotkey.

Comment: I am trying to help, but I notice that you keep changing the scope. Ofcourse if you want to capture all keys, this solution does not scale. Your request only mentioned 3 hotkeys and did not mention the use for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think this is the final script....

Normally all keys behave as usual unless you press F6, then during 3 seconds you can use the hotkeys. As soon as you used a hotkey the behaviour falls back to normal again (the 3 seconds are only in case you do not press a hotkey). When you press F6 twice it will send F6. Let me know if you found an easier solution as this is relativey complex.

```
FormatTime, DateRef, %TimeNow%, yyyyMMdd ; Store current date in variable DateRef
MyLogFile = %A_ScriptDir%\LogFile-%DateRef%.txt ; Define the name of the log file for today.
FormatTime, TimeAbsolute, %TimeNow%, HH:mm:ss
FileAppend, | %TimeAbsolute% | Your hotkey and possibly in which application`n`r,%MyLogFile% ; Write logfile
SpecialF6:=1
Suspend, On
Return

$F6::
Suspend, Permit
If SpecialF6
{
Suspend, Off
ToolTip Hotkeys On for 3 seconds,A_ScreenWidth/2-50,0
SpecialF6:=0
SetTimer, SuspendOn, 3000
Return
}
else
{
    Send, {F6}
    MyText = F6
    Gosub, WriteClose
}
Return

SuspendOn:
Suspend, On
SetTimer, SuspendOn, Off
ToolTip
SpecialF6:=1
return

F5::
Run explorer
MyText = F5 Run Explorer
Gosub, WriteClose
Return

t::
Run notepad
MyText = t Run Notepad
Gosub, WriteClose
Return

!+5::
Run cmd
MyText = Alt Shift 5 Run Command
Gosub, WriteClose
return

WriteClose:
Suspend, On
SetTimer, SuspendOn, Off
FormatTime, TimeAbsolute, %TimeNow%, HH:mm:ss
ToolTip
SpecialF6:=1
FileAppend, | %TimeAbsolute% | %MyText%`n`r,%MyLogFile% ; Write logfile
Exit
```